# When does this linear matrix equation have a unique symmetric, positive definite solution?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, positivity, matrix-equations

I encountered the following matrix equation for $A, N, Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $A^T=-A$ and $N^T=-N$

$$[X,A]+N^TXN+Q = 0$$

where $Q$ is symmetric, positive definite. My final goal is to understand under which conditions this equation has a unique symmetric, positive definite solution $X$.

In this case, we have that $$\langle [X,A]y,y\rangle=-\langle Qy,y\rangle-\langle XNy,Ny \rangle \le 0\ ,$$ so that $2 \Re\left(\langle Ay,Xy\rangle \right)=\langle Ay,Xy \rangle + \overline{\langle Ay,Xy \rangle} \le 0$ for all $y \in \mathbb{C}^n.$

Thus, if $X$ is positive and symmetric, then we must have  $\Re\left(\langle AXy,y\rangle \right) \ge 0$ as well.

As a first step, I would like to know if this matrix equation has ever been studied before or if anybody sees some valuable properties of this equation.

Comment: What is the difference between the $*$ and $T$ superscripts (when working over $\mathbb R$)?

Comment: there is no difference

Comment: Suppose that a solution $X$ exists. Taking the trace you get $tr(Q)=0$ and hence $Q=0$; similarly $tr(N^TXN)=0$ and hence $N^TXN=0$. Thus, you need to search for $X$ satisfying $XA-AX=0$ and $XN=0$. In any case, these equations are homogenous, so that if there is a solution, then there will be many solutions.

Comment: If you are interested in existence of symmetric solution to general matrix polynomial equations, maybe https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.04204 is of interest to you.

Comment: @AndreasThom How do you get $\operatorname{Tr} Q = 0$?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni; the trace of the commutator is zero and the other two summands are positive as $X$ was assumed to be positive definite.

Answer (score 1):

Since you look for literature pointers: similar equations appear in the study of **stochastic linear-quadratic control problems**. See for instance the work of Tobias Damm; for instance [this paper](http://www.math.chalmers.se/~tonyst/papers/NLAA_damm_mena_stillfjord.pdf) (Damm, Mena, Stillfjord, *Numerical Solution of the Finite Horizon Stochastic Linear Quadratic Control Problem*), and in particular Theorem 2.1.

Comment: Peter Benner, Tobias Damm, [Lyapunov Equations, Energy Functionals, and Model Order Reduction of Bilinear and Stochastic Systems](http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/fileadmin/AGs/techno/user_files/damm/Publikationen/BennerDamm11.pdf), SIAM Journal on Control and Optimization, Volume 49, Issue 2, 2011.

Answer (score 0):

We have the following linear matrix equation in $\mathrm X$

$$\mathrm X \mathrm A - \mathrm A \mathrm X + \mathrm N^{\top} \mathrm X \mathrm N + \mathrm Q = \mathrm O_n$$

where all the matrices are real and $n \times n$. Matrices $\mathrm A$ and $\mathrm N$ are skew-symmetric. Multiplying both sides by $-1$, we rewrite the matrix equation as follows

$$\mathrm A \mathrm X - \mathrm X \mathrm A - \mathrm N^{\top} \mathrm X \mathrm N = \mathrm Q$$

Exploiting the skew-symmetry of $\mathrm A$ and $\mathrm N$, we obtain

$$\mathrm A \mathrm X + \mathrm X \mathrm A^{\top} - \mathrm N \mathrm X \mathrm N^{\top} = \mathrm Q$$

[Vectorizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) both sides, we obtain a linear system of $n^2$ equations in $n^2$ unknowns

$$\underbrace{\left( (\mathrm I_n \otimes \mathrm A) + (\mathrm A \otimes \mathrm I_n) - (\mathrm N \otimes \mathrm N) \right)}_{=: \mathrm M} \, \mbox{vec} (\mathrm X) = \mbox{vec} (\mathrm Q)$$

If $\mathrm M$ has **full rank**, then the linear matrix equation has *only one* solution, which may or may not be positive definite. If $\mathrm M$ does *not* have full rank and the linear system is

- consistent, then the linear matrix equation has *infinitely many* solutions, and we can look for one that is positive definite. This is the most interesting case.
- inconsistent, then the linear matrix equation has *no* solution.

Let $\mathrm C_i \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ be the "un-vectorization" of the $i$-th row of matrix $\mathrm M$. We then have $n^2$ equations

$$\langle \mathrm C_i, \mathrm X \rangle = \langle \mathrm e_i, \mbox{vec} (\mathrm Q) \rangle$$

each defining an affine space in $\mathbb R^{n \times n}$. Relaxing the positive definiteness constraint $\mathrm X \succ \mathrm O_n$ and imposing the positive *semidefiniteness* constraint $\mathrm X \succeq \mathrm O_n$ instead, we have the intersection of $n^2$ affine spaces with the positive semidefinite cone, i.e., we have a (closed) [spectrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrahedron).

- If this spectrahedron has *no interior* (i.e., if it is "flat"), then there is no positive definite solution to the given linear matrix equation.
- If this spectrahedron has an interior, then there are *infinitely many* positive definite solutions to the given linear matrix equation. Note that there can be no *unique* positive definite solution.

We can attempt to find one of the positive definite solutions by solving the following **semidefinite program** (SDP)

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \langle \mathrm O_n, \mathrm X \rangle\\ \text{subject to} & \langle \mathrm C_1, \mathrm X \rangle \,\,= q_{11}\\ & \langle \mathrm C_2, \mathrm X \rangle \,\,= q_{21}\\ & \quad\quad\quad \vdots\\ & \langle \mathrm C_{n^2}, \mathrm X \rangle = q_{nn}\\ & \mathrm X \succeq \mathrm O_n\end{array}$$

where $q_{ij}$ is the $(i,j)$-th entry of $\mathrm Q$. The objective function is zero because we would like to find a solution in the interior of the spectrahedron, not on its boundary (where it would only be positive semidefinite). If the SDP is *infeasible*, then there are neither positive semidefinite nor positive definite solutions.